# open man (or info) pages from the same position where you left off last time

Tags: vim, man, less, pager, more

I treat man pages is the primary source of documentation about installed software.
I would like to use them not only as a reference, but actually read them from beginning to end.

And here comes the question. When I close the man page, next time I want it to be opened at the place I left off. Is it possible?

Ideally it would work with less, which is the default system pager. But I am OK to change it to any pager that will do the trick.

Standalone vim for example remembers position the file was read at last time. There might be some way to use it as a pager remembering position.

Please try your idea before posting comments/answer.

Comment: You can use the "most" pager, which supports resuming where you left off by default.

Comment: so does vim, but not when used as a pager. Neither seems most to work.
 I tried with simple 'export PAGER=most' and it does not resume.

Comment: Possibly because the actual filename may be random?

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: @SergeyGuzenkov have you tried refreshing the bash by source ~/.bashrc after exporting it to shell? or may be alternatively try adding vim like this export PAGER="vim -R".

Comment: Also, try adding the following lines in .vimrc 
`au BufReadPost * if line("'\") > 0 && line("'\") <= line("$") | execute "normal g'\"" | endif` and
`au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | execute "normal! g`\"" | endif`

Comment: On ubuntu there's no temporary file, looks like it just gets piped to the page. Using any of the keyboard shortcuts in `more` that should show the current filename just gives you the line-number in the active view.

Comment: @tink We don't know what Unix this user is using.

Comment: With `man` from man-db, `MANPAGER=env man man` shows the name of the man page is made available in the `MAN_PN` environment  variable, so a custom pager could use that to remember last cursor position for a given man page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp, using Vim as the viewer. Works with Vim 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.

(Please translate to your favorite language; this is mine, I made it myself.)

This file is called `mnpgr.tl` and lives in some location `/path/to/mnpgr.tl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env txr

(defvarl home-dir (getenv "HOME"))

(defvarl mnpgr-dir (path-cat home-dir ".mnpgr-dir"))

(defvarl vim-commands
         (join-with "|"
                    '("hi def link CtrlHUnderline Special"
                      "hi def link CtrlHBold Keyword"
                      "set syntax=ctrlh"
                      "syntax match CtrlHHide /.\\b/  contained conceal"
                      "set conceallevel=2"
                      "set concealcursor=nc"
                      "map q :q!\r")))

(ensure-dir mnpgr-dir)

(match @(or `@page(@section)`     ;; for "man whatever"
            `@page\\.@section`)   ;; for "man -l file.1"
       (getenv "MAN_PN")
  (with-resources ((rendered-file (path-cat mnpgr-dir `@page.@section`)
                                  (remove-path rendered-file)))
    (with-stream (s (open-file rendered-file "w"))
      (whilet ((line (get-line)))
        (put-line line s)))
    (sh `vim +'@{vim-commands}' '@{rendered-file}' < /dev/tty`)))
```

We install it as the man pager using:

```
export MANPAGER=/path/to/mnpgr.tl
```

Notes:

1. The program uses a work directory in your `$HOME` called `.mnpgr-dir`.
2. It captures the output of `man` and saves it into a file in the work directory. The name of the file is calculated from the `MAN_PN` environment variable which gives us the man page and section number.
3. We run Vim on that file. Because it has a stable name, Vim can remember the last position.
4. We don't need to keep the file, so it is removed. (I used the `with-resources` macro for scoped resource control.)
5. The file contains `^H` (backspace) overstrike encoding. Vim 8 has a 2005-dated syntax definition for this which provides a syntaax (but not a file type) called `ctrlh`. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work. It uses the `Ignore` highlight group for the overstruck characters, which doesn't get concealed. I suspect that older Vim versions might have concealed the `Ignore` highlight group. We use the `+` feature of the Vim command-line to inject some commands to both select the `ctrlh` syntax and hot-patch it into behaving better. We also reassign the bold and underline highlight groups into colored categories, rather than the default bold and underline.
6. We add a `map` command so that <kbd>q</kbd> will quit. This idea is cribbed from Vim's `+MANPAGER` mode. (We don't use `+MANPAGER` because it requires pages rendered to plain text without the backspace overstrikes, and then imposes the hacky `man` syntax highlighting in which all the original bolds and underlines markup is lost.)

Bugs:

1. **Items highlighted by the backspace overstrikes are not searchable**. This is a big deal, and a possible show-stopper.
   One way to deal with it would be to use a preprocessor which converts the items into another notation. For instance an underlined word like `_^Hw_^Ho_^Hr_^Hd` could be converted to `^word^`. An appropriate syntax highlighting definition would conceal the underscores and colorize the word, leaving the word searchable. This is exactly how highlighted words work in the Vim manual.
2. If you re-load the man page with `:e %`, you lose the hot-patches to the `ctrlh` syntax, so you see all the backspaces as `^H` as well as the overstruck characters. For a better solution, we should define our own syntax highlighting definition file type and syntax like `mnpgr`, and use that as a suffix for the file.
3. Won't distinguish man pages that clash to the same name. This could happen if you sometimes view a man page using `man -l <file>` and your system has a same-named page in `/usr/share/man`. E.g. suppose you have the sources to GNU Bash cloned in your system and in that tree you view `man -l bash.1`. And suppose you also use `man bash` (who doesn't).  Those two both map to the rendered file `~/.mnpgr-dir/bash.1`.
4. The `sh` function is used, which is like `system()` in C; there are potential escaping issues. If `vim-commands` or `rendered-file` were to contain a single quote, it would break the single quoting that is wrapped around them.

---

This is now a mini project [whose home is here](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/mnpgr).

It has its own Vim syntax definition file `mnpgr.vim`. The program parses the backspace overstrikes and produces its own notation, which is handled by `mnpgr.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

If the session doesn't have to survive a reboot, you can just use POSIX job control. Put the `man` job in the background with Ctrl-Z, and return to it with `fg`.

```
$ jobs
[1]   Stopped                 man gcc
[2]-  Stopped                 man bash
[3]+  Stopped                 info make
```

If I want to continue reading the Bash man page where I left off, just

```
$ fg %2
```

Comment: The solution has to survive a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the man page(s) as PDF and read them with your favorite PDF viewer.  This has the additional benefit of letting you see actual typesetting instead of being limited to the capabilities of character-cell terminal emulators.

Take, for example, [*groff*'s own man pages formatted as a single 383-page document](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/groff-man-pages.pdf).

If you have a pile of uncompressed *man*(7) and/or *mdoc*(7) files handy, try *groff* 1.23.0 for best results.

```
groff -Rpet -mandoc -Tpdf page.1 page.2 page.3 ...
```

But you can also view individual man page documents handily with *man*, of course.

```
zcat -f $(man -w groff_man) | man -l -Tpdf - >| groff_man.pdf
```

The foregoing uses *man-db* 2.9.4 for its *man* implementation.

Comment: the problem with pdf is that it can't be read in the terminal. The text will not get wrapped when you recize your window.
But for those that rely on GUI this will work. 
Thank you for the suggestion!